# Combine NSDictionaries

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, cocoa-touch

Goal:  Combine all NSDictionaries returned with one common key value 'delay' into a single NSMutablearry that I can use to compare the results (true or false) to place either a green or red pin on a map.
This code brings back the airport data in JSON that I convert to a dictionary of the requested airports.  There are a number of keys, but in this part of the code I am only interested in one - 'delay' that I want to combine into one NSMutablearry.
Because I can only request one airport at a time, it brings back each requested airport individually and I get 9 sets of data.  What I want is the 9 delay keys all in one array for the 9 different airports.

```
`- (void)configureData
{

self.airportCodes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:

                     @"ATL",
                     @"BOS",
                     @"BWI",
                     @"CLT",
                     @"CVG",
                     @"DEN",
                     @"EWR",
                     @"ORD",
                     @"SFO",
                     nil];

NSUInteger airportCount = self.airportCodes.count;


for(int i=0; i < airportCount;i++){

    NSURL *url = [self urlWithSearchText:[self.airportCodes objectAtIndex: i]];
    NSString *jsonString = [self performAirportRequestWithURL:url];
    if (jsonString == nil) {
        [self showNetworkError];

    }


    NSDictionary *dictionary = [self parseJSON:jsonString];
    if (dictionary == nil) {
        [self showNetworkError];
    }

    self.airportDelays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:9];


    [self parseDelay:dictionary];

    //NSLog(@"AP Delays %@",self.airportDelays);
} 

return;
}


-  (void)parseDelay:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{


//self.delay = [dictionary objectForKey:@"delay"];
[self.airportDelays addObject:dictionary];



NSLog(@"AP Delays %@",self.airportDelays);

return;
}

- (NSURL *)urlWithSearchText:(NSString *)searchText
{
NSString *escapedSearchText = 
[searchText    stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *urlString = 
[NSString stringWithFormat:
@"http://services.faa.gov/airport/status/%@? format=application/json", escapedSearchText];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
return url;
}

- (NSString *)performAirportRequestWithURL:(NSURL *)url
{
NSError *error;
NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:
url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (resultString == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Download Error: %@", error);
    return nil;
}
return resultString;
}

- (void)showNetworkError
{
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Whoops..."
                          message:@"There was an error reading 
                          from the FAA Server. Please      try again."
                          delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
}


- (NSDictionary *)parseJSON:(NSString *)jsonString
{
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *error;
id resultObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:
kNilOptions     error:&error];
if (resultObject == nil) {
    NSLog(@"JSON Error: %@", error);
    return nil;

    if (![resultObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSLog(@"JSON Error: Expected dictionary");
        return nil;
    }
}
return resultObject;
}

@end`
```

Comment: that is quite a lot of text… how about some code you have tried?

Comment: Post the code that combines the dictionaries into the array, don't be embarassed, we all started somewhere

Comment: just so you know, make four spaces at the beginning of each line, and your code will be formatted on this page. You can also put code inside tickmarks, the opposite key of the apostrophe. Mine is under Escape. like this `code`

Comment: For posting the code please edit the question.

Comment: You will have to pick one of your attempts and add it to your question (and PLEASE not as a comment). otherwise we won't be able to help you. this code fragments you have posted in the comments are not helpful.

Comment: ok, replacing all your text with code isnt helpful either. you should describe, what you try to accomplish and what is happening instead.

Comment: Basically I use the FAA Airport web service to retrieve airport data.  In another viewcontroller I allow a user to select an airport and then show detailed information on that airport.  I also have another view, a map view that I show all airports with pins.

Comment: I want to be able to change the pin color if the airport shows "true" for the key 'delay'  Everything works as I can retrieve all the data, display it and plot the pins on the map.  But to change the color, I want to pull the delay key and set the pin color depending on the result (true or false).  I can print out the dictionary, but get all 9 separately and I am trying to combine them into one.  Sorry, I am new, be gentle.

Comment: Be careful with NSDictionaries as they are not ordered like a NSArray. They are key pair values, so if you loop through, it may not be in the same order in your array. Just a thought though, why dont you start off using a NSMutableDictionary instead of NSMutableArray??

Comment: I actually tried it with both ways - same result - I'm just not using the proper code to combine them - that's what I'm still seardhing for.  I really don't have to have the data in a NSMutablearry -  I just need to take the one key value out of each of the 9 dictionaries and combine them into one so that I can compare the key values to be true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your issue: You are instantiating the airportDelays array every time a new dictionary is created, therefore, you are only adding one dictionary before destroying the airportDelay array and creating a new one. See below

```
self.airportDelays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:9];


[self parseDelay:dictionary];
```

Should be

```
if (!self.airportDelays) {
    self.airportDelays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:9];
}
[self parseDelay:dictionary];
```

I'm also weary of you using a for loop to do your network operations. You should probably be using a different queueing mechanism, where the program waits for the response for the first dictionary before asking the webservice for the next.  That might be a different lesson for a different time though.

Good luck

Comment: Yep!! It works!! I will take your sugestion to redo the network request and wait for a response prior for asking for the next dictionary.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: Cool. Just so you know the reasoning, just because you start one network operation and then another, it won't necessarily end with responses in that order. Sometimes it may be appropriate to wait until a previous operation finishes before starting another, especially if it concerns the same object(s)

Comment: I agree - at least I know how to fix that part of the code myself!!  Again, thanks for taking the time to answer the question - I know it was a newbie question, but I think I researched so much that I overlooked the obvious!! Thanks!